# Choosing a proper return type for a function returning a map of errors

Tags: scala

I have a function which either should return `Map[String, Seq[String]]` as sequence of the errors with the keys (in case there **are** errors) or return success (probably, `Unit`). I wonder, what's the best return type for it?

```
def foo1(a: Int): Map[String, Seq[String]]
def foo2(a: Int): Option[Map[String, Seq[String]]]
def foo3(a: Int): Either[Map[String, Seq[String]], ???]
//def foo4(a: Int): something else?
```

If the first case, it would have to return `Map["", Seq()]` if there are no errors and, to my mind, it doesn't look elegant. In the second case, it would return `None` and that's ok but it seems redundant. The same for the third case, but there is one more issue - what would I return as `Right`?

What do you think?

Comment: It looks like primarily opinion-based question to me. So here is my opinion: it should either be named `getErrors` (or similar) to stress that result is a collection of errors with result type `Option[...]` or you should use `scalaz.Validation` for result type: `Validation[Map[String, Seq[String]], Unit]` or `ValidationNEL[(String, Seq[String]), Unit]`.

Comment: @senia wouldn't it better to check map.isEmpty on client?

Comment: @senia do you think return Option[Map[String, Seq[String]]] is sensible? Why not just Map[String, Seq[String]]?

Comment: I guess the best solution here is `Validation`: `def validateFoo(a: Foo): ValidationNEL[ErrorType, Foo]`. With custom `ErrorType`.

Comment: @senia, but I'm not using scalaz.

Comment: If you can use `scalaz` you should at least try it. `Validation` is very useful. See my answer to your next question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem with the first option is that it's easy to forget to check `isEmpty` on the return result. If most clients would naturally do the right thing with an empty map (e.g. because they just iterate on it, or get number of errors), this is the best one. Option 2 is acceptable if you name method something like `getErrors` (as @senia says), option 3 is as well (with `Either[Map[String, Seq[String]], Unit]`).